# Why was a young actor in age makeup cast in the Battlestar Galactica miniseries, rather than an older actor?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, battlestar-galactica

In the first scene, the mid-sixties looking Armistice Officer is played by then 31-year-old [Ryan Robbins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0730455/). The part has no lines and the character never appears again (though the actor appears again playing a different part in Caprica).

Can anyone explain why they cast a younger actor and aged him with makeup versus simply casting an actor in his mid-fifties?

Comment: Followup question: why did the cyclons send a delegation to Armistice Station just to blow it up moments later?

Comment: @stannius - It might be worth you asking your own question :-)

Comment: In-universe answer please!

Comment: Uh, I think that the in-universe answer is that he was OLD

Comment: @npst How could this have an in-universe answer when it's not an in-universe question? Specifically, the age of the actor can't be an in-universe fact.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I suspect that npst was making a joke. :-)

Comment: @stannius: If I were functionally immortal (guaranteed resurrection with full memory retention), there's no real drawback to it (resource wastage is negligible). Maybe they wanted a front row seat to the turning point in what was going to be a historic event.

Comment: @stannius perhaps they wanted to make certain everyone was there. This isn't the sort of thing you get a second chance at.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

There is a deleted scene where he is shown going to the station each year, but the Cylons never show up. The passage of time is shown by him aging each time...when they didn't include most of this, they were left with the scene with the age made-up actor.

Comment: Can you provide a clip of this deleted scene?  Where did you see this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was on my dvd of the miniseries which unfortunately don't have access to right now. Also if i did have it i don't know how to add clips...

Comment: Maybe see if it's on YouTube?

Comment: No, I think you nailed it @WiggotheWookie. Finding the clip for it would be gravy, but this makes perfect sense.

Comment: You could link to, for example, [this page](http://www.galactica.tv/battlestar-galactica-2003-guest-stars/ryan-robbins-armistice-station-officer-/-boxey-s-father.html) which mentions the "going there every year" bit, though it doesn't explicitly talk about the scene being filmed or deleted.

Comment: Deleted?  I thought I remember that’s how it opened.

Comment: I couldn't find the actual video, but the deleted scene is mentioned on [this Wiki](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Armistice_Officer)